# How to optimize OpenCL kernel use of trigonometric functions?

Tags: c, encryption, parallel-processing, opencl

I am new to OpenCL and I am struggling to fasten up my application. The OpenCL kernel takes much more time than using a sequential approach. I am trying to encrypt a 4096 x 4096 image. This is the kernel that I've written:

```
__kernel void image_XOR(
__constant const unsigned int *inputImage,
__global unsigned int *outputImage,
__constant double *serpentineR,
__constant double *nonce,
__global unsigned int *signature) {
unsigned int i = get_global_id(0);

double decimalsPwr = pow(10.0, 15.0), serpentine2Pwr = pow(2.0, (*serpentineR));
unsigned int aux;

unsigned long long XORseq;
unsigned int decimals =  floor(decimalsPwr * fabs(*nonce));

XORseq = decimals ^ (unsigned long long) floor(( 1.0 / (i + 1)) * decimalsPwr);

if (i % 2 == 1) { 
    aux = floor(decimalsPwr * fabs( atan( 1.0 / tan( decimalsPwr * (double) XORseq))));
} else {
    aux = floor(decimalsPwr * fabs(sin(serpentine2Pwr * (double)XORseq) * cos(serpentine2Pwr * (double)XORseq)));
}

aux = aux << 8u; // comment if alfa chanel should be crypted as well
aux = aux >> 8u;

outputImage[i] = inputImage[i] ^ aux;

*signature = *signature ^ inputImage[i] ^ aux;}
```

Note: If I comment out these lines the code is a lot faster (0.5s from 4s)

```
if (i % 2 == 1) { 
    aux = floor(decimalsPwr * fabs( atan( 1.0 / tan( decimalsPwr * (double) XORseq))));
} else {
    aux = floor(decimalsPwr * fabs(sin(serpentine2Pwr * (double)XORseq) * cos(serpentine2Pwr * (double)XORseq)));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me start by saying I'm not familiar with this encryption scheme, so some of my comments may not be useful.

Before we try to spend much time optimising it, are you sure it produces consistent results? Floating-point precision isn't well defined in OpenCL, especially not for trig functions, so if you need to decrypt on another system (e.g. different GPU brand), are you obtaining sufficient precision? For example, are you able to decrypt an image on the CPU after encrypting it on the GPU?

Beyond that, some observations:

- As @doqtor has pointed out already, you have a bunch of values which do not vary across work items, so precalculate those and pass them in directly.
- `decimals =  floor(decimalsPwr * fabs(*nonce));` looks like it will overflow, assuming your `nonce` gets anywhere near `1.0`. Is that intended?
- With GPUs typically scheduling threads in lock-step, you want adjacent work items following the same conditional path. This is the opposite of what you're doing with `if (i % 2 == 1)`. I suggest rearranging the calculation across work items such that 32 or 64 adjacent work items follow one path and the next group follows the other path.
  For example, `i = (i & 0xffffff80) | ((i & 0x1) << 6) | ((i & 0x3e) >> 1)` should process items `0, 2, 4, 6, … 124, 126, 1, 3, 5, … 125, 127, 128, 130, …` in that order. (It will require an integer multiple of 128 input pixels though unless you specially handle other cases.)
  This should prevent all threads performing all possible calculations and throwing away half of them.
- You should be able to use some trig identities to simplify calculations. For example, *sin(θ)cos(θ) = sin(2θ)/2*. This will save you evaluating both `cos` and `sin`.
- As I already mentioned in the comment on @doqtor's answer, `*signature = *signature ^ inputImage[i] ^ aux;` is not atomic, so it will not generate a predictable result. Use `atomic_xor()` instead. (You may want to collect the signature of a work group and only have one work item in the group update the global signature, as atomic global ops carry a performance penalty.)
- As you are heavily trig bound, and trig functions on many GPUs don't use the same parts of the FPU as multiplication and addition, you may want to experiment with using explicit implementations of some of the trig functions so they can be better parallelised. Depending on the precision you need, you could also try using look-up tables.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain whats the difference between regular or and atomic_xor? Also, This is just a part of my application. I will try to make use of POCL, which may ensure the portability of the code on various platforms, at least to an extent. I am at the very beginning of using OpenCL and, because of that, I am not aware of all the problems that I might encounter. Sorry for that :D

Comment: Also, `i = (i & 0xffffff80) | ((i & 0x1) << 6) | ((i & 0x3e) >> 1)` should replace the `i % 2 == 1`? I do not understand where all those values come from.

Comment: `*signature = *signature ^ a` Does the following: 1. read the value pointed to by `signature` 2. xor it with `a` 3. write the result to the memory location pointed to by `signature`. If the memory at `*signature` has changed between steps (1.) and (3.), then those changes will simply be overwritten. Atomic operations avoid this. You should probably read up on memory synchronisation in OpenCL in general, there's a lot more to this subject than I can cover in an SO comment.

Comment: That rearranging of the bits in `i` would be done immediately after `i = get_global_id(0);`. The idea is that we reverse the order of the lowest bit and the 6 next higher bits, so that the low bit of `i` for work-items 0 through 63 is always 0, i.e. the first 64 work items process the even numbers, and the next 64 items process the odd numbers. This means the first group of 64 will all take the `else` and the second group will take the `if`. I recommend writing a small program to print the numbers 0 through 255 before and after putting them through this operation to see what I mean.

Comment: 6 bits (hence 64 items) are an arbitrary choice, you can experiment with different values as it will also affect the memory access patterns.

Answer (score 4):

`double decimalsPwr = pow(10.0, 15.0), serpentine2Pwr = pow(2.0, (*serpentineR));`

`serpentineR` is used as scalar so pass it as scalar not via global memory which is much slower. But here I would go even further and do not do above calculations on GPU side. Just pre-calculate them in CPU and pass to the kernel. Imagine that every this calculation has to be performed 4096 x 4096 times - what a waste of resources!

`unsigned int decimals =  floor(decimalsPwr * fabs(*nonce));` - same here, pre-calculate on CPU and pass as parameter to the kernel. It needs to be calculated only once.

Another suggestion would be to avoid using 64 bit types in the kernel as much as possible. In most cases they are much slower in compare to 32 bit types on GPU. Let's check for example GeForce RTX 2060. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Nvidia_graphics_processing_units#GeForce_20_series) states that the processing power for single fp precision is 5241.60 GFLOPS but for double fp precision is just 163.80 GFLOPS. That is 32x difference! If reducing precision is not an option then many times is worth to perform the 64 bit calculations in CPU and pass the results to GPU for the remaining calculations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand what you are suggesting and I will try to change the code accordingly, but, as stated in the problem, those 2 lines of code, which cannot be calculated beforehand, take a lot of time. One more question.. Would it help to copy the array in the __local memory? If so, how shall that be done, I have tried but didn't work so well.

Comment: It doesn't look like it would help to use local memory here. Just avoid too many reads/writes on global memory, for example I can see `inputImage[i]` is read twice but instead could be read once into register value. Also sometimes `__constant` is slower than `__global` so you may want to change that and check.

Comment: Note that `*signature = *signature ^ inputImage[i] ^ aux;` is not atomic, so will not generate a predictable result.

Comment: It looks like `signature` should be an array.

Comment: @doqtor Not if the intention is a scalar cryptographic signature, which is what it looks like to me.

Answer (score 2):

Just some observations...

> unsigned long long XORseq;

AFAIK, there is no such type in OpenCL. It might work, but it's unportable code. Also, OpenCL types are not C types; unlike C types, "unsigned long" is always 64 bits in OpenCL. IOW, OpenCL "unsigned long" == uint64_t in C; similarly for other types.

Also, trigonometric functions in OpenCL have predefined requirements on range and allowed error of result (in ULP). These requirements are so strict that most GPUs (especially consumer) simply don't have the hardware to calculate this with a single hardware instruction, because (for games) you don't need it 99.999% of time, and it would just take up silicon. GPUs do have hardware sin/cos instructions, but these have much more limited precision and range - just enough for graphics. You can use them from OpenCL with "native_cos" and "native_sin". The "full" sin/cos (which is what your code has) is calculated using some routines - so it's quite slow. Additionally, your code using doubles instead of floats slows it down further (by 8-32x on consumer GPUs).

I'm not sure why you decided to use double trigo for encryption, but i doubt it'll ever be very fast on consumer GPUs.

Plus there's another problem - different OpenCL implementations (AMD, Nvidia, Intel etc) can return different results for trigo functions; OpenCL only specifies the *maximum* ULP error. So e.g. if you try to encrypt on nvidia GPU opencl & then decrypt on intel CPU opencl, you won't necessarily get back the original.